# How to manually add controllers in Java Swagger-UI?

Tags: java, web, swagger, swagger-ui

You can access your swagger-ui from http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html.

All of the @Controllers annotations will automatically be added to the UI.

However, I have one dynamic Controller which accepts various uri requests (http://localhost:8080/api/*).

I want to be able to manually decide which controllers will be added to my swagger-ui and which won't.

(I can provide all the controllers descriptions (uri, method, parameters, etc...))

Is there a way to do that?